# Travis | Android: Platform tools v26.0.2 not installing

Tags: android, github, continuous-integration, travis-ci, platform-tools

On 26th October my Travis CI builds suddenly started to fail and none of the mentioned workarounds are working for me (like https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6193). The exact issue being reported in my lint report:

`The SDK platform-tools version (23.0.1) is too old to check APIs compiled with API 25; please update`

Here's the Travis job's log: https://api.travis-ci.org/jobs/294869249/log.txt?deansi=true

The link to my PR: https://github.com/edx/edx-app-android/pull/1020

`platform-tools revision 26.0.2` was recently released whose download is finishing with the wrong checksum, thus Travis is using the fallback `platform-tools revision 23.0.1` for running lint on my project causing the issue.

Here's the error excerpt from the job's log (https://api.travis-ci.org/jobs/294869249/log.txt?deansi=true):

> Installing Archives:
>
> Preparing to install archives
>
> Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 26.0.2
>
> Download finished with wrong checksum. Expected
>   b8130e7c390496cff12bf9355739bd41eed6a0a5, got
>   668ff8e319715175ff628ad52b124f154275fe2d.
>
> Done. Nothing was installed.

Any idea for a fix?

Comment: I have the same problem. Also a have same checksum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got auto solved somehow on Travis's side and I had to do nothing on my end.

More details can be found in this issue that I created on Travis's Github:

https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8676